# White strange pixels in html canvas after using gradient fillRect with opacity multiple time

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, gradient

I was using html canvas, creating context filling with alpha gradient color multiple time, and then I've noticed some white dot artifacts as the image shown below.

[image]
<sub>Testing done in Chrome with Windows, using Nvidia GPU.</sub>

It seems to be those pixels outside the limited gradient bound will create the dots. Code provided as below to reproduce the image:

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas')
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')
// The context is still using default composite option: source-over
var i = 50
while (i > 0) {
  //  The gradient bound is smaller than canvas size
  const grd = ctx.createLinearGradient(
    Math.round(Math.random() * 30) + 100,
    Math.round(Math.random() * 30) + 100,
    Math.round(Math.random() * 100) + 100,
    Math.round(Math.random() * 100) + 100,
  )
  grd.addColorStop(0, '#0001')  // Alpha with about 10% opacity make this problem noticeable
  grd.addColorStop(1.0, '#fff1')
  ctx.fillStyle = grd
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 200, 200)
  i -= 1
}
```

```html
<canvas id='canvas' width=200 height=200/>
```

**What cause those white dots in canvas?**

Did I do some wrong in canvas? Or is there some interpolation(dithering) during each draw call? Not going to deal with it but just curious what's the reason.

Comment: `Math.random()` and multiplying it won't give you an integer.  I suspect that's part of this, among other rounding.

Comment: @Brad Yes indeed. So I wrap it into round function, it's actually take user mouse position in my work, so I guess a round number cause the issue. **Update:** With both float or round number cause the issue

Comment: If Firefox, no dots, but I get the stripiness that one gets in dark gradients from not having enough grey levels. In Chrome, I get the dots but the gradients come out slightly different.

Comment: Thanks for the testing, so it must be some drawing issue that was implemented in browser. And a strongly doubt about dithering since chrome canvas enable dithering gradient by default.